# Why my ADT is always showing Reindexing Repository?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, adt

I am using ADT (eclipse) to develop my android app. Maintaining repository in git. But always it shows re-indexing repository. What does it mean? Can I stop this process and make it manual?

Another problem is it always shows 700+M of 742M. I assume it's virtual memory usage. As long as I am adding more codes ADT becomes slow. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unchecking `Prefereces->Team->Git->Automatic refresh->Refresh resources when index changes`